# Unable to Resolve UI-Card - Salesforce Playground Composition Recipe

Tags: lightning-web-components, ui

Experimenting with LWC and getting the following error following a [recipe](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes-oss/tree/master/src/modules/recipe/compositionContactSearch):

```
Unable to resolve ui/card from root/compositionContactSearch/compositionContactSearch.html
```

Am I missing an import or something? Is ui-card and ui-input a component? If so, from where, I'm not seeing uiCard or uiInput in the modules folder. I see there is a ui/app folder that is a sibling to modules parent, but there is no mention of ui-card or ui-input in those classes.

Lightning Recipes OSS: https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes-oss

**App.js**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

}
```

**App.html**

```
<template>
                <c-composition-contact-search></c-composition-contact-search>
</template>
```

**compositionContactSearch.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

const DELAY = 350;

    export default class CompositionContactSearch extends LightningElement {
        error;

        handleKeyChange(event) {
            window.clearTimeout(this.delayTimeout);
            const searchKey = event.target.value;
            this.delayTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                try {
                    this.contacts = contacts();
                } catch (e) {
                    this.error = e;
                }
            }, DELAY);
        }

            get contacts() {
            return [
                {
                    Id: 'Edit the name and description of your component.',
                    icon: 'utility:edit',
                },
                {
                    Id:
                        'Create permanent, shareable URLs that anyone can view within your org.',
                    icon: 'utility:save',
                },
                {
                    Id: 'View changes to code instantly with Live Compilation.',
                    icon: 'utility:refresh',
                },
                {
                    Id: 'Style your components with SLDS.',
                    icon: 'utility:brush',
                },
                {
                    Id: 'Download and upload components as zip files.',
                    icon: 'utility:download',
                },
            ];
        }
    }
```

**compositionContactSearch.html**

```
<template>
    <ui-card title="CompositionContactSearch">
        <div>
            <ui-input
                type="search"
                onchange={handleKeyChange}
                label="Search"
            ></ui-input>
            <template if:true={contacts}>
                <template for:each={contacts} for:item="contact">
                    <recipe-contact-tile
                        key={contact.Id}
                        contact={contact}
                    ></recipe-contact-tile>
                </template>
            </template>
        </div>
        <template if:true={error}>
            <recipe-error-panel errors={error}></recipe-error-panel>
        </template>
        <recipe-view-source
            source="recipe/compositionContactSearch"
            slot="footer"
        >
            Create an experience component by assembling multiple child
            components. Type a few characters in the search bar to experience
            the recipe.
        </recipe-view-source>
    </ui-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mentioned in one of the issues of the repository. The `ui-card` is a base component and is not present in the UI folder.

It is a dependency in package.xml and comes from this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lwc-recipes-oss-ui-components).

If you want to see the code, browse the files [here](https://npm.runkit.com/lwc-recipes-oss-ui-components/src/modules/ui/card/card.html?t=1586532987345).

See more details [here](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes-oss/issues/53).